# How can we Remove the AppData of an electron msi Application when we uninstall it ?(using electron-builder)

Tags: electron, electron-builder, windows-installer

I have created an electron Application and packaged it using `electron-builder`, I installed the msi installer then after uninstalling the application the App data is not getting deleted. Are there any flags i need to add in build configuration for msi to remove AppData.

Expected: AppData should be removed after uninstalling the application.

Comment: Why is this tagged with NSIS and MSI? Pick one or the other.

Comment: may be some one who worked with electron and using both  nsis, msi may answer my quesion. As we use in our application

Comment: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1188

Comment: @MayankVadiya this I tried for exe it is going fine but for msi its not working

Answer (score 4):

for windows:

```
"nsis": {
  "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true
},
```

add to builder.yml

Comment: The issue is with msi installer, I was doing `deleteAppDataOnUninstall` flag at nsis in my project currently it is only working fine with  .exe installer but not working for msi installer

Comment: your solution is not working do you have any better approach

Comment: no yet, I'm still confused with mac to uninstall app to delete user data

Comment: This only works with the one-click installer.

Comment: What about macOS, is there a way to delete localStorage data from renderer when electron app is uninstalled?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) then you have 2 solutions

**First solution:**

Set `deleteAppDataOnUninstall = false` Boolean - one-click installer only. Whether to delete app data on uninstall.

```
"build": {
    "nsis": {
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true
    }
 }
```

**Second solution:**

Custom NSIS script with `customUnInstall` macro

create `uninstaller.nsh` and put in `package.json` in `build` key

```
!macro customInstall
  RMDir /r "$APPDATA\${APP_PACKAGE_NAME}"
!macroend
```

```
"build": {
    "nsis": {
      "include": "uninstaller.nsh"
    }
  }
```

Reference: https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script